# Values Not Posted in foreach codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want Delete group with checkbox but value of id not posted
i tested var_dump($_POST) and respond is " array(0) { }  "
and i posted textbox and checkbox before foreach and its worked and posted
but values in  foreach not posted ...
Where is my mistake?

Controller:

```html
function news()
{
        if ($this->session->userdata('role') != 'admin')
            redirect(base_url(), 'refresh');

        $page_data['page_name']  = 'news';
        $page_data['page_title'] = get_phrase('news');

        $page_data['newslist'] = $this->News_model->get_All_News();
        $this->load->view('backend/index', $page_data);
}

function news_del(){
        $newsid = $this->input->post('news');
            foreach ($newsid as $news_id) {
                $this->news_model->news_group_delete($news_id);
            }
            $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', get_phrase('data_deleted'));
        return redirect(base_url() . 'admin/news/', 'refresh');
    }
```

Model :

```html
function get_All_News(){
  $this->db->order_by('id','DESC');
  $query = $this->db->get_where('news',array('type'=> '1'));
  return $query->result();
}

function news_group_delete($news_id){
  $this->db->where('id',$news_id);
  $this->db->delete('news');
}
```

View :

```html
<div class="pull-right">
  <?php echo form_open('admin/news_del'); ?>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-cons" value="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Are You Sure?')">
    </div>
</div>

<?php
  $count = 1;
  foreach($newslist as $row):?>
<tr>
  <td class="v-align-middle">
    <input type="checkbox" name="news[]" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" />
  </td>
  <td class="v-align-middle">
    <?php echo $count++;?>
  </td>

 </tr>
  <?php endforeach;?>

<?php echo form_close();?>
```

Comment: Have you loaded your model in your controller?... $this->load->model('news_model');

Comment: In case it wasn't obvious enough by the `HTML`, `JAVASCRIPT`, and `CSS` labels, the Code Snippets feature is only meant for running client-side code, not PHP.  Edited.  Thanks.

Comment: The file has to be named `News_model.php`. But you load it with lowercase `$this->load->model('news_model')` (like Webcode.ie said). And call it with lowercase `$page_data['newslist'] = $this->news_model->get_All_News();`

Comment: @ourmandave he is probably using old version of CI . Ali which version of CI you are using?

Comment: @WebCode.ie Yes it loaded in config/autoload

Comment: @ourmandave model and controller Work correctly but values of checkbox in foreach not posted

Comment: @MalikMudassar version 3.1.2

Comment: @AliAsadi I have taken the time to copy your code to my clean install of CI3 and the only issue that I came across was what ourmandave said. You need to change this `$this->news_model->news_group_delete($news_id);` to this `$this->News_model->news_group_delete($news_id);` - go ahead and try it.

Comment: @WebCode.ie i tested but not posted values , and i print var_dump and values not returned...

Comment: @AliAsadi Can you please use the inspector tool in your browser and take a screenshot of the rendered code in your browser source (from your form). Then update your answer with that. I am curious to see what information is actually rendered in your form before it is submitted.

Comment: @WebCode.ie thanks for helping i putted form_open before table and then work Thanks :)